# Dedicated submit buttons to save form data individually to database, using same servelet

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp form which shows up as a data entry screen for user. There are 2 inputs on the form. Data for one of the input field 'A' to be entered based on the combo selection. where as the other input is simple input field 'B'. There are two submit buttons one saves the values of field 'A'. and other field 'B'.

Problem is when data is already entered for 'B' and if the submit button for 'A' is clicked, page refreshes and the data entered for 'A' is saved in db (which is working as expected). But, values entered for 'B' is lost due to page refresh after submit.

My question here is how to avoid the resetting of filed 'B' values on submitting 'A'.

Comment: Are those two submit buttons for single form?

Comment: Yes, both submit buttons are on same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest one of three ways:

1) Send both values to the servlet, and upon return pass back the B value in the request scope, as follows:

You will have following line in your

```
request.setAttribute("bFieldValue", bFieldValue);
```

Then in JSP you can access this data using the expression language like below

```
${accountList}
```

2) Store the value in local storage (HTML5)

```
localStorage.setItem("fieldBValue", value);
```

Then retrieve on refresh:

```
document.getElementById("fieldB").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("fieldBValue");
```

3) AJAX Request (Credit to Sid for suggestion)

You can use jQuery AJAX to submit only the form - this stops page refresh so is ideal. Something like this:

```
$("#formB").ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: '/endpoint'
    data: formB.serialize(),
    success: function(response){  

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

    }         
} );
```

And submit the form like so to trigger the above JS:

```
$("#formB").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution.  Another way is to use Ajax, which will enable you to have finer controls on what is sent to the server and the page won't be refreshed.